# Android Loadermanager onloadfinished method was not called on Orientation Change when it is declared outside on create method

Tags: initialization, android-loadermanager, orientation-changes

i am initializing the loader in action bar navigation list item callback method.  By default first item will be selected in action bar navigation list. based on navitem selection i am initializing the loader. at the launch of application the loader call back methods are calling fine. but when i change the orientation the loader callback methods are not getting called.
but if i initialize the loader in oncreate method the loader callback methods are getting called after orientation change also.

**My Code:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
 getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {



                         if(itemPosition == 0 || itemPosition ==1)
                        {
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putString(Constatnts.Url, serviceurl +"/getgroups/"+shared.getString("StationID", "null")+"/0");
                            b.putInt(Constatnts.selection, itemPosition);
                            b.putString(Constatnts.xmlroles, session.getUserDetails().get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME).get(1));
                            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, b, MainActivity.this);
                        }

                        else if(itemPosition == 2)
                        {

                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putString(Constatnts.Url, serviceurl +"/getchanneldetails/"+shared.getString("StationID", "null")+"/1/0");
                            b.putInt(Constatnts.selection, itemPosition);
                            b.putString(Constatnts.xmlroles, session.getUserDetails().get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME).get(1));
                            getLoaderManager().initLoader(itemPosition, b, MainActivity.this);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putString(Constatnts.Url, serviceurl+"/Getcategories/"+shared.getString("StationID", "null")+"");
                            b.putInt(Constatnts.selection, itemPosition);
                            b.putString(Constatnts.xmlroles, session.getUserDetails().get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME).get(1));
                            getLoaderManager().initLoader(itemPosition, b, MainActivity.this);

                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                });
}
```

The loader callback methods are not getting called after orientation change with the above method.

**but if i place the below code outside the navigationlistcallbacks and inside oncreate method the loader callback methods are getting called **

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
                                b.putString(Constatnts.Url, serviceurl +"/getgroups/"+shared.getString("StationID", "null")+"/0");
                                b.putInt(Constatnts.selection, itemPosition);
                                b.putString(Constatnts.xmlroles, session.getUserDetails().get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME).get(1));
                                getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, b, MainActivity.this);
```

how can i reload the data after  orientation change if **initloader** is in setListNavigationCallbacks methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callbacks are only invoked after the loader is initiated (`initLoader`)or restarted (`restartLoader`). With `initLoader` the cached result can be used after an orientation change but it has to be called explicitly to deliver the data in `onLoadFinished`. Hence, you have to call it in your `onCreate` method with the `itemPosition` as the loader id, but only if an `itemPosition` is already set.

I've stripped your example code to illustrate what I mean:

```
// static so that it survives orientation change.  
private static int mSelectedItemPosition = -1; // -1 = Not selected

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (mSelectedItemPosition != -1) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(mSelectedItemPosition, null, MainActivity.this);
    }

    getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener()       {

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    if(itemPosition == 0 || itemPosition ==1) {
        mSelectedItemPosition = 0;
        Bundle b = ...
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(mSelectedItemPosition, b, MainActivity.this);
    }
    else if(itemPosition == 2) {
        mSelectedItemPosition = itemPosition;
        Bundle b = ...
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(mSelectedItemPosition, b, MainActivity.this);
    }
    else {
        mSelectedItemPosition = itemPosition;
        Bundle b = ...
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(mSelectedItemPosition, b, MainActivity.this);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: if i tried to restore the selection by using this line  actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(bundle != null
            ? bundle.getInt(CURRENT_FRAGMENT_TAG)
            : 0);  the backgroud method is calling twice. can u give me any suggestion on this.

Comment: Check if initLoader is called twice: once from onCreate and once from onNavigationItemSelected.

Comment: yes it is calling twice from initLoader and onNavigationitemSelected  how to avoid that can u give me a suggestion.